# Validation of Submitting Data

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm new to programming and C#, I'm trying to make a small Electronic Voting System, How can I make the votes invalid when the voter votes an excess number of candidates. For example: The user voted 7 candidates instead of 6 in councilor position, how can I make his vote invalid or doesn't let him to submit his votes till he make it 6.

```
private void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        if (MessageBox.Show("Confirm and View your Votes?", "Close Application", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Voting Successful", "Application Closed!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE candidate SET cTally = cTally + 1 where cName like @cname or cName like @vName", con))
            {

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cname", cb_president.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vName", cb_vpresident.Text);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            foreach (object item in lb_councilor.SelectedItems)
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE candidate SET cTally = cTally + 1 where cName like @coname", con))
                {

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@coname", (item as DataRowView)["cName"].ToString());

                    Console.WriteLine((item as DataRowView)["cName"].ToString());
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE voters SET isVoted = 1 where userName like @uname", con))
                {

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", userid );

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
            }
            this.Close();
            new Form4().Show();
            this.Hide();


        }
        else
        {
            this.Activate();
        }   
    }

    private void Frm_voteview_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.VotingSystemv2ConnectionString);
        con.Open();

        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'votingSystemv2DataSet7.candidate' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.candidateTableAdapter2.Fill(this.votingSystemv2DataSet7.candidate);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'votingSystemv2DataSet5.candidate' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.candidateTableAdapter1.Fill(this.votingSystemv2DataSet5.candidate);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'votingSystemv2DataSet4.candidate' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.candidateTableAdapter.Fill(this.votingSystemv2DataSet4.candidate);

    }

    private void dgv_councilor_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void dgv_councilor_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Frm_voteview_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.VotingSystemv2ConnectionString);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'votingSystemv2DataSet7.candidate' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.candidateTableAdapter2.Fill(this.votingSystemv2DataSet7.candidate);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'votingSystemv2DataSet5.candidate' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.candidateTableAdapter1.Fill(this.votingSystemv2DataSet5.candidate);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'votingSystemv2DataSet4.candidate' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.candidateTableAdapter.Fill(this.votingSystemv2DataSet4.candidate);
        con.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form9().Show();
    }

    private void cb_president_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void lb_councilor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: From which control you get the votes?

Comment: What do you mean by which control i got the votes? @EmrahSüngü

Comment: I have not been able to read your code completely but i do not see where you get who the user voted for. Edit: oh you are directly updating the table

Answer (score 0):

Currently your code is writing to your database directly, and pulling into your views from your database. Diagramming that relationship would look like:

```
View < > Database
```

You might find solving this problem easier if you try for a [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

With C#, we can instead create objects to keep track of some of our logic for us, that are in between the View and the Database. This would look more like:

```
View < > Poll < > Database
```

In more detail, your objects might look like:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Poll
{
    var this.Candidates = new List<Candidate>();
    var this.MaxVotes;

    Poll(List<Candidate> candidates, int allowedVotes)
    {
       this.Candidates = candidates;
       this.MaxVotes = allowedVotes;
    }

    public Vote(List<Candidate> selectedCandidates)
    {
       if (selectedCandidates.Count > this.MaxVotes)
       {
           // throw a new Exception or warn the user if the user has too many votes and make them fix it
       }

       else // If the vote passes our check, we can save it to the database
       {
          // save the votes to the database
       }
    }
}

public class Candidate
{
    this.Name;

    Candidate(string name)
    {
       this.Name = name;
    }
}
```